# Scanf %i with letters gives negative number?

Tags: c, string, math, integer, scanf

I've essentially solved my issue by slapping together a work around, but I'm just wanting to understand why this behavior happens so first my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996) // Just so MVS stops having a meltdown over scanf.

/* Simple question and answer of math equasion. */

int main() 
{
    printf("What is 5 + 5?\n\nAnswer: ");

    int userInput;
    if (scanf("%i", &userInput) && userInput != (5 + 5)) // Give 'userInput' a variable from scanf and compare to hard coded answer.
    {
        printf("\nIncorrect!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("\nCorrect!\n"); // Else without the 'else'.
    return 1;
}
```

It's simple enough, hard coded math question, and requesting an answer from the user. Intended response would be correct for the answer solved matching `userInput` and anything that doesn't match is considered incorrect. When I pass it a bunch of letters or just simply "asdf" it treats it as correct and spits out a negative number: -858993460.

My work around is adding `|| userInput < 0` to my if statement like this:

`if (scanf("%i", &userInput) && userInput != (5 + 5) || userInput < 0)`

So essentially the issue has been treated with some flextape slapped on it but what I can't seem to answer is the question: "Why does it spit out that negative number no matter what letters or non-numeric characters I feed it?"

My apologies if this has already been answered. I tried searching with whatever keywords I could think of to no avail.

Comment: What do you mean by "spits out a negative number"? There's nothing that prints a number in the code shown. Anyway, the core issue is that the code is not entirely correct. If an invalid input is entered, `scanf` will return `EOF`. In that case your original code still treats it as the correct case. The check should be `scanf() == 1`.

Comment: If I add `printf("i%", userInput);` below the correct when typing in the letters, that's where it gives me said negative number. Sorry, I should have added that to the code.

Comment: Well that's because `scanf` fails and doesn't set any value for `userInput`. Since `userInput` is not initialised it will just contain garbage data in that case. You must not use `userInput` unless `scanf` succeeds.

Comment: Ah, so upon failure it then assigns userInput that negative number? Doesn't matter what's entered, that number doesn't change which is what I was curious about. Where exactly does that negative number come from?

Comment: No, if `scanf ` fails it does not touch `userInput` at all. It's just whatever random garbage happens to be there in the variable. Accessing variables that are uninitalised is Undefined Behaviour and the value is thus unpredictable and has no meaning.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes better sense. It's just random junk then but it failed and didn't know what to do so it just treated it as correct, if I'm understanding that correctly?

Comment: @kaylum Actually, not UB in this case unless the implementation has trap representations.  The fact that `userInput` had its address taken prevents it.

Comment: *it just treated it as correct*. What is the first "it"? If you mean the `printf` then no it's not treating the variable as "correct". `printf` just prints whatever you tell it to and it does not do any checks on the validity of the variable.

Comment: @dbush Not sure what you mean. The comments are in reference to `printf("i%", userInput);` in the case which the `scanf` fails. The OP has not shown that code in the post but mentions it in the comments. So why is it not UB to print the `userInput` variable which has never been set?

Comment: @kaylum To better clarify I was assuming then the if statement failed it's check because of this and the `printf` instruction just printed junk data with my particular instruction to state anything but what's caught by the if statement is correct.

Comment: @kaylum Section 6.3.2.1p2 on lvalue conversions:  *"If the  lvalue  designates  an  object  of  automatic  storage  duration  that  could  have  been declared with the `register` storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is  uninitialized  (not  declared  with  an  initializer  and  no  assignment  to  it  has  been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined."*  So reading an unintialized variable isn't strictly UB if its address was taken.  Then it would only be UB if the implementation has trap representations *and* the garbage value happens to be one.

Comment: @dbush Interesting. I must admit I was not aware of that.  But does the list of UB listed in J.2 apply here? *The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate*?

Comment: Also, you almost certainly never want to use `scanf` with `%i`, and should perhaps use `%d` instead. `%i` will accept octal numbers, so if you enter 012 then that is **correct too** as it 012 Dec is 010 Dec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scanf` function returns the number of items matched, so in a boolean contents it evaluates to true if you entered a number and false if your didn't.  It also means that no value is written to `userInput`, so its value (because it was not initialized) is still **indeterminate**.

This means your condition says that the answer is "Incorrect" if the user entered a number *and* it's not 10, so it's considered correct if you didn't enter a number.  You instead want to print "Incorrect" if *either* a number is *not* entered *or* the entered number is not 10:

```
if (!scanf("%i", &userInput) || userInput != (5 + 5))
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the answer. I'm still getting used to the logic conventions. My initial thoughts with the extra instructions makes me think the better route now with my code snippet there is to swap the conditions around.

Instead of making a if statement for something being wrong, I should probably opt to make an if statement for the answer being correct, and if it doesn't match `(5 + 5)` then it'll just pass it through to the other section.

As far as I understand now though, `userInput` just results in random junk data so when printed it gives me said output if met with letters?

Comment: @BluZero You want to check if `scanf` was successful or not first (which this code does), then only read `userInput` if it was.

Comment: If end of input is reached before the first valid conversion or matching failure, `EOF` is returned (generally `-1`) which would also test true with `scanf("%i", &userInput)`